# ASP MVC: Create Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression programatically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to generate a MVC-editor with the function

```
System.Web.Mvc.Html.EditorExtensions.EditorFor<TModel, TValue>(
       this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, 
       object htmlAttributes = null)
```

The problem is the

```
Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression
```

because I have only the name of the property. I'm sure the property exist and I can get the actual instance of the Model.

How can I create the correct parameter?

Edit: To make it more clear:
I have the model, I have the name of the property and want to create the Expression>.

Thanks!

Peter

Comment: Did you try `Html.EditorFor(model=>model.SomeProperty);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer of Johnathan Barclay guides me the right way!

Instead of html.EditorFor I now use html.Editor.

Here an extraction from the code of the generator-class:

```
 public static MvcHtmlString GenerateStepTwo(this HtmlHelper<InputModell> html, InputModell modell)
    {
     ...
     foreach (var actField in fieldsSorted)
        {
        ...
        editor = html.Editor(fieldname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", style = "max-width:200px;min-width:100px" } });

        all.AppendLine(AddOpenImageFunc(editor, fieldname));
...
}
return all;
```

Thanks!
Peter

Answer (score 1):

If you have your property name as a string, use the [Editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/web-frameworks/ff406519%28v%3Dvs.100%29) extension method rather than `EditorFor`.

e.g.

```
@Html.Editor("YourProperty", new { htmlAttributes = new { ..
```